# Celery worker displaying "unknown option -A" on windows

Tags: python, flask, rabbitmq, celery, celery-task

Celery worker suddenly not working and displaying error message saying unknown option -A.
I am running celery 5.0.0 on windows within virtual environment of python.
The command is

```
pipenv run celery worker -A <celery_file> -l info
```

Error message is as follows:

```
Usage: celery worker [OPTIONS]
Try 'celery worker --help' for help.

Error: no such option: -A
```

Please let me know why this error is occurring, as I am unable to find the cause of it.

Answer (score 1):

Worker has no flag -A, I think you want to use that on the celery level.

Like this:

```
pipenv run celery -A worker <celery_file> -l info
```

Now I am not on Windows so I can't verify but it seems to be in line with the commands in the [official documentation on workers](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/workers.html).

```
$ celery -A proj worker -l info
```

Comment: I checked the same command with -A option on celery version 4.4.7, it works fine

Comment: I see that you already made a bug report on this, good. Maybe you can answer your own question and close it? Hopefully you will get a fix soon.

Answer (score 0):

[3.1.25 was the last version](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/history/index.html) that works on windows(just tested on my win10 machine)

```
pip install celery==3.1.25
```

In your Python interpreter, type the following commands:

```
>>> import os
>>> import sys

>>> os.path.dirname(sys.executable)

'C:\\python\python'
```

note celery have [dropped support for Windows](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/history/whatsnew-4.0.html#removed-features)(since v4).

```
"c:\python\python" -m celery -A your-application worker -Q your-queue -l info  --concurrency=300
```

or using other format

```
celery worker --app=app.app --pool=your-pool --loglevel=INFO
```

Comment: Yes officially celery has dropped support for windows from version 4, but I found a way to make it work. With celery version 4.4.7 this command works fine (with -A or --app). With version 5.0.0 I think there is an issue. I have raised a bug on this in github. https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/6363

Answer (score 0):

The correct way (for those using pipenv) to start the worker should be something like `pipenv run celery -A <package.module> worker -l info` . Note that -A comes before worker command as it is general Celery option. Look at `pipenv run celery --help` for more details.

Also, I notice you use the latest 5.0.0 Celery - they have [changed the command-line handler](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/whatsnew-5.0.html#step-1-adjust-your-command-line-invocation) so switching to 5.0.0 may cause problems with some of your old startup scripts.